# Remove a white background on listview android

Tags: android

First at all in my apps there are a custom lisview use a xml to define every listrow.

But on my items i just call it a android:color/transparent and the result is i get a transparent only on my first row!

In the other row there are some white block lay below my list custom item

I have try to remove it by set a value android:background="@android:color/transparent" on my listview tag

Here my code :D

This is my custom item listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp" >

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/libraryIconImageView"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/file_holder" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/librayFolderImageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/libraryIconImageView"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <customtextview.widget.TypefaceBoldTextView
        android:id="@+id/libraryBookNameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="library_tree_item_childrenlist"
        android:textColor="@color/text_color_bold"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <customtextview.widget.TypefaceTextView
        android:id="@+id/libraryFileNameTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="library_tree_item_name"
        android:textColor="@color/color_black"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/librayFolderImageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@null" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is how i call the listview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/tiki.vn.reader"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/library_background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/headerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/navProgressView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="3dp" >

            <fr.castorflex.android.smoothprogressbar.SmoothProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/navProgress"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                app:spbStyle="@style/Widget.ProgressBar.PullToRefresh"
                app:spb_color="#1A9CCB"
                app:spb_stroke_width="3dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <customtextview.widget.TypefaceTextView
            android:id="@+id/current_path"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/navProgressView"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:ellipsize="start"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/base_color"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:background="@color/base_color" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="12dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="12dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_bg"
            android:overScrollMode="never"
            android:scrollbars="none" />

        <customtextview.widget.TypefaceButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="58dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-2dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_border_login"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="+ Add OPDS..."
            android:textColor="@color/color_white"
            android:textSize="19sp" />
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the result is

[image]

The fisrt row is right as my expectations the row is trasnparent and then i can add my custom xml shape like a radius shape with a curves corner.

In the second row i appear a white shape below my custom listrow item

Please help :D i'm gonna be crazy with these things for weeks :(

Comment: Can you re-add the original imgur link please. The image is too low quality here to tell what we are looking at and it appears to be edited out.

Comment: Here the pic http://i.imgur.com/IZyyF2f.jpg @Mgamerz